# How to get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors from sklearn spectral clustering?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I am trying out spectral clustering from sklearn, and to set the optimal cluster number, I would like to use the method suggested in this paper "Self-tuning spectral clustering" (published in NIPS). This method requires the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, and I realise that sklearn spectral clustering does not provide it.

Is there a way to get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors from sklearn spectral clustering?

Here is the paper bibtex

```
@article{zelnik2005self,
  title={Self-tuning spectral clustering},
  author={Zelnik-Manor, Lihi and Perona, Pietro},
  year={2005},
  publisher={MIT Press}
}
```

Comment: Could you cite properly your paper ? Can't find it

Comment: Use the source code of sklearn. It's **open source**, not a black box.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the following source files:

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f0ab589f/sklearn/cluster/spectral.py#L259

then

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f0ab589f/sklearn/manifold/spectral_embedding_.py#L308

You can ultimately see that one way to compute the eigen-values/vectors is

```
lambdas, diffusion_map = eigh(laplacian)
```

Here, `eigh` refers to [`scipy.linalg.eigh`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eigh.html) as mentioned on top of the source file.

Answer (score 1):

Like @anony-mousse said, you can find it in the source code.

Inside of the sklean source code in `sklearn\cluster\spectral.py` there's this line:

```
maps = spectral_embedding(affinity...
```

`maps` contains the eigenvectors. By default, `spectral_embedding` only outputs the eigenvectors but you can modify it to output the eigenvalues (typically named `lambdas`). You can also simply compute them yourself from the affinity matrix with your eigensolver of choice.

Comment: Does this answer your Q Michael?